# 3D surface is messed up for some angles

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to plot a 3d graph with MatPlotLib. However, when I render it, it comes out really weird from some angles, but alright from others.

The equation for this particular graph is:

```
a(x,y)= -0.25(xy)^2 + 1.25xy^(2) + y^(2) - 0.25x^(2)y - 1.75xy  + 2.5x^(2) - 1.5x
```

Plt has no problem loading simpler equations such as `x^(2) + y^(2)` or `x+y+2xy`. It can usually handle it with or without cmap.

#### `x^2 + y^2 with cmap`

[image: x^2 + y^2 with cmap]

#### `x^2 + y^2 without cmap`

[image: x^2 + y^2 without cmap]

```py
 x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 50)
    y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 50)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = f(X, Y)
 
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
    ax.scatter3D(input_vals[:, 0], input_vals[:, 1], output[:], c=output[:])
    ax.set(xlim=(-6,6), ylim=(-6,6), zlim=(-6,6))
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

The first lines just help create my function and the variables. I'm not too sure where the problem is.

I tried removing `rstride` and `cstride` from my `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)` that didn't work and the graph still looked messy from some angles. One thing that did work was removing `cmap`. Before the graph would be impossible to discern and would just be a mess of whatever value I put in.

Most of the things I need to plot will be more complex than this. I'm mostly dealing with rectangular equations too. Is there a fix for this or should I try using a different 3D Plotting program?

[image: A bad angle]

[image: A good angle]

[image: Another good angle]

[image: With cmap with glitches]

[image: With cmap, without glitches]

Still hard to discern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was forcing the aspect and the limits. They're turned off now.

```py
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 50)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def f(x, y):
    return -0.25*x*y**2 + 1.25*x*y**2 + y**2 - 0.25*x**2 *y - 1.75*x*y + 2.5*x**2 - 1.5*x
    
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1)
# ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
# ax.scatter3D(X, Y, Z, c=Z)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was helpful.